# Getting ArrayList with SQLOpenHelper not working

Tags: java, android, sqliteopenhelper

I have a problem with my `SQLiteOpenHelper` class.
I have a database with printer manufacturers and details of any kind of printer.
I try to get all manufacturer from my database with this code and returning them in a arraylist.

```
// Read database for All printer manufacturers and return a list
public ArrayList<String> getPrManufacturer(){
    ArrayList<String> manufacturerList = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(CoDeskContract.Printer.TABLE_NAME,
                             printerManuProjection, null, null, null, null, null,null);

    // If cursor is not null and manufacturer List 
    // does not contains Manufacturer in the list then add it!
    if ((cursor != null) && (cursor.getCount()>0)){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            String cursorManufacturer = cursor.getString(0);
            //Checking for manufacturer in the list
            for(String manufacturerInList:manufacturerList){
                if (!manufacturerInList.equals(cursorManufacturer))
                    manufacturerList.add(cursorManufacturer);               
            }                   
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // Return list of manufacturers from database
    return manufacturerList;
}
```

I want every manufacturer to be once in a list.
Somehow i cant to get it to work.
Im still a newbie.

Thanks for any Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. In the beginning, when your list `manufacturerInList` is empty then it will not go inside `for(String manufacturerInList:manufacturerList){` loop and hence it will never add any entry in the list.
2. Once you fix your problem 1, still it will not work as `if (!manufacturerInList.equals(cursorManufacturer))` checks against each entry in the list and adds the non matching entry in the list possibly multiple times.

To fix the issue, you have two options.

**Option1**: Use `contains` as:

```
            if (!manufacturerList.contains(cursorManufacturer)) {
                 manufacturerList.add(cursorManufacturer); 
            }
```

**Option2**: Use a `matchFound` boolean flag as:

```
        String cursorManufacturer = cursor.getString(0);
        boolean matchFound = false;

        //Checking for manufacturer in the list
        for(String manufacturerInList:manufacturerList){
            if (manufacturerInList.equals(cursorManufacturer)){
                 matchFound = true;
                 break;
            }
        }                   
        if(!matchFound){ // <- doesn't exit in the list
            manufacturerList.add(cursorManufacturer); 
        }
```

Comment: Thanks that you explained this to me :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the distinct keyword in SQLite (http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html). Use SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(String query, String[] args) for that.

`db.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT name FROM " + CoDeskContract.Printer.TABLE_NAME,null);`

Comment: This can also be done using the query() method's `distinct` parameter, see <http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)> .

Answer (score 0):

Use [ArrayList.contains(Object elem)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)  to check if item is exist in ArrayList or not Change your code as:

```
  // does not contains Manufacturer in the list then add it!
    if ((cursor != null) && (cursor.getCount()>0)){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            String cursorManufacturer = cursor.getString(0);
            //Checking for manufacturer in the list
           if (!manufacturerList.contains(cursorManufacturer)) {
                     manufacturerList.add(cursorManufacturer); 
                } else {
                    System.out.println("cursorManufacturernot found");
                }              
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```